# Which is the correct way of using SIUSBXP from Go?

Tags: go

I have a hardware that is accessed via SIUSBXP (Silicon Labs).

Is there a way to access the hardware directly from Go?

Or should I write a C/C++ wrapper and links it to my Go program?

Comment: i some-how dont understand the question here, it's the operation system that decide whether you can access the hardware directly not the language, right? if considering the driver, cgo maybe helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically about this dll, I made this animal to works:

```
SiUSBXp                      = syscall.MustLoadDLL("SiUSBXp.dll")
SIGetNumDevices              = SiUSBXp.MustFindProc("SI_GetNumDevices")
SIGetProductString           = SiUSBXp.MustFindProc("SI_GetProductString")
.
.
.
... and so on...
```

That way, the dll is loaded by the first line and the required functions are referenced in the other lines.

To call a function, for example:

```
func GetNumDevices() int {
var lpdwNumDevices int
r1, _, _ := SIGetNumDevices.Call(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&lpdwNumDevices)))

if int(r1) == StatusSISUCCESS {
    if lpdwNumDevices == 1 {
        log.Println(lpdwNumDevices,"hardware(s) found")
    }
    return lpdwNumDevices
}

return -1
}
```

This kind of code can be used when you need to communicate with some another dll, as far I can see.

Note that I didn't use cgo.